# Is there any benefit of storing lambda function into std::function?

Tags: c++, c++11, std-function

From https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function

```
void print_num(int i)
{
    std::cout << i << '\n';
}
 
int main()
{
    // store a free function
    std::function<void(int)> f_display = print_num;
    f_display(-9);

    // store a lambda
    std::function<void()> f_display_42 = []() { print_num(42); };
    f_display_42();
}
```

What is the advantage of storing a lambda into a name than the previous approach ?

Comment: The answer is "Type erasure"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantage is that you don't need to know what is the type of the callable in order to store it. For instance, how do you declare an `std::vector` of things that can be called as a function? With `std::function` is easy:

```
std::vector<std::function<void()>> handler_list;
```

You can easily store in `handler_list` lambdas, explicit function objects or function pointers, without caring for their actual type. Another use is inside a class:

```
class Something {
public:
    void register_callback(std::function<void()> callback)
    {
        this->callback = callback;
    }

    //...

private:
    std::function<void()> callback;
    //...
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the simplest answer for the easiest understanding.